# Why mozilla firefox log many messages from socket.io 1.2.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I implement socket.io 1.2.1 server script on a Centos server, and open a client window on mozilla firefox (v34.0.5). I see many logs in my firebug console. please see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58691844/firebug%20logs.PNG

[image: firebug logs]

when I copy the socket.io server script to my localhost and run it, and open a client window, I dont see any logs in my firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.io` uses the `debug` module for its output. In node this means you toggle debug output via an environment variable called `DEBUG`. In the browser however, debug output is toggled by setting `localStorage.debug`. If you open up the console and do `console.log(localStorage.debug);` you should see it output some non-empty string. If you set it to a blank string, the debug output should go away.

Comment: thanks!! your answer guide me to the right path. what I did to solve this:
1. open console on firefox, type: localStorage.debug = "";
2. refresh the page